# Uploading a file on a server with Android Volley

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I am trying to do do the following tutorial, to send files to a server in an Android application using Volley.

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

So I did all (php files, sql database and android project) but there is something I didn't succeed to solve. When I run the application and I send a file, I have the message coming from my php file telling that the file was sucessfuly uploaded, and a new line is created in the sql database.

The problem is that the folder 'uploads' on the server remains empty.

Thanks you very much in advance for your answers, best regards

Comment: The problem seems to be in your php code. Maybe the path of the file is not correct. I would suggest to check file_put_contents method. It returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Did you know how can i verify this ?

If I put an echo the android app crashes...

Comment: If you use XAMPP you should be able to see the logs. Just do a quick search on the internet to see how to to that. The crash on Android is maybe because you don't handle the response correctly but you should first check what that method returns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the server is a raspberry and I cannot install XAMPP on it apparently. (not supporting arm architecture)

Do you know an other way to check the response of file_put_contents ?

Comment: I haven't worked with raspberry before but there should be a way to see the logs of your server written in php. Just do a bit of research and you'll find how to do that.